# Getting Id as null while calling a microservice from another microservice

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, microservices, openfeign

I have 2 services question,quiz. In question I have questiondId,quizId, question,options,answer in Question service. In Quiz service  quizId, title, maxMarks,noOfQuestions and List of Questions (not stored in DB). So, when I am calling a particular quiId  I get all detials and also Questions . BUt the problem is int the questions list the Id of question is displaying as null.
I used feign clients to call question service and quiz service . What is the possibly mistake I have done.Please help me.

Getting all questions of a specific quizID(https://i.stack.imgur.com/90OwU.png)
Getting information of a specific quizID
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBiZO.png)

Comment: can you share code snippets?

Comment: please, provide some details like the code and the stack you are using, error messages, expected behaviour and also use the proper formatting for showing code and data. The articles [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [minimum reproducible examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) can help you to improve the question